# python send email with nonenglish characters?

Tags: python

Hi all I am new to python and this is my really first programm.
I am sending email message

```
msg = Message("Hello",
              sender="e@gmail.com",
              recipients=["e@gmail.com"])
msg.body = request.form['firstname']

mail.send(msg)


request.form['firstname']  # some field in form which can be in Russian.
```

But on my mailI get not letters but symbols like this: �
what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding from the Russian charset to Ascii:

```
msg.body = request.form['firstname'].decode('cp855')
```

Comment: I think `857` chip set is better

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' (С)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an encoding issue of python scrypt. I propose the following solution:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
fromaddr = 'user_me@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'user_you@gmail.com'
msg = MIMEText('Текст на русском', 'plain')
username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'pwd'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I checked it out with my gmail account and got the correct russian characters.

PS
My environment is P3.4 + VS2012

Comment: On python 3.4 I'd still preferably use the default UTF-8 instead of cp1251 for source code encoding.

Comment: If I change cp1251 to UTF-8 the scrypt generates an exception after encounter with russian symbols. So I think that cp1251 is obligatory for the solution.

Comment: Of course for that to work, your file also needs to be saved with the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I do nothing inside VS2012 (default settings). If change manually the encoding to UTF-8 in notepad++ outside VS it stops working.

Comment: It seems that VS saves the file in cp1251 encoding before execution.